# Moving top.menu to its own structural reference via local.xml

Tags: ce-1.8.1.0, menu, local.xml

Does anyone known if it is possible to move top.menu to its own structural reference through local.xml ?

By default it is inserted in header.phtml

I have removed the callout from header.phtml and inserted it in the page layout files (1column,3columns etc) directly below the header call.

```
   <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topMenu') ?>
```

In local.xml i have then added

```
    <reference name="header">
        <action method="unsetChild"><name>topMenu</name></action>
    </reference>
```

I would usually then add the reference name where i want it to go but as top.menu resided within header by default it does not have its own structural reference.

I tried adding it as topMenu but ofcourse this failed as the reference doesnt exist.

```
    <reference name="topMenu">
        <action method="insert"><blockName>top.menu</blockName></action>
    </reference>
```

Would anyone know a solution to this.

p.s. i am using magento 1.8.1.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have removed the callout from header.phtml and inserted it in the page layout files (1column,3columns etc) directly below the header call.

Then you will have to make `topMenu` block a children of `root` block.

What I did in my project was to add a `<block>` children of `root` block in `page.xml`.

#### Using <update> tag.

Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7661107/what-does-the-update-element-do-in-magento-layout-xml

So you would could also solve it in `local.xml`:

```
<default>
    <reference name="root">
       <update handle="topMenu" />
    </reference>
</default>
```

Comment: Thanks but i already tried the root reference infact it was the first method i tried. I have also used page.xml to do this before but i'm looking to do all edits in local.xml.

Comment: Couldnt get this to work through local.xml alone so in the end i built a layout module. The update tag does seem to be answer its just figuring out how to structure it. I dont have enough time to play with it currently but i will revisit this when i do as it would be so much easier to do everything through local.xml. Thanks again !

Comment: Glad you solved that! You're welcome.